# How to horizontally mirror visual selections in place in vim?

Tags: vim

I've a set of flat files that represent designs (For the curious, these are fort blueprints for the game Dwarf Fortress):

One of them looks like this:

```
`,`,`,`,`,`,d,d,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,d,d
`,`,`,`,`,`,d,d,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,d,d
`,`,d,d,d,d,d,d,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,d,d
`,`,d,d,d,d,d,d,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,d,d
`,`,d,d,d,d,d,d,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,d,d
`,`,d,d,d,d,d,d,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,d,d
`,`,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d
`,`,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d
`,`,d,d,d,d,d,d,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,d,d
`,`,d,d,d,d,d,d,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,d,d
`,`,d,d,d,d,d,d,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,d,d
`,`,d,d,d,d,d,d,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,d,d
`,`,`,`,`,`,d,d,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,d,d
`,`,`,`,`,`,d,d,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,d,d
`,`,`,`,`,`,d,d,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,d,d
```

I want to mirror the pattern on the left, and paste it on the right.

Using simple visual selection I can yank and paste the pattern from right to left, which results in:

```
`,`,`,`,`,`,d,d,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,d,d`,`,`,`,`,`,d,d,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,
`,`,`,`,`,`,d,d,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,d,d`,`,`,`,`,`,d,d,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,
`,`,d,d,d,d,d,d,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,d,d`,`,d,d,d,d,d,d,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,
`,`,d,d,d,d,d,d,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,d,d`,`,d,d,d,d,d,d,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,
`,`,d,d,d,d,d,d,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,d,d`,`,d,d,d,d,d,d,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,
`,`,d,d,d,d,d,d,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,d,d`,`,d,d,d,d,d,d,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,
`,`,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d`,`,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,
`,`,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d`,`,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,
`,`,d,d,d,d,d,d,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,d,d`,`,d,d,d,d,d,d,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,
`,`,d,d,d,d,d,d,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,d,d`,`,d,d,d,d,d,d,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,
`,`,d,d,d,d,d,d,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,d,d`,`,d,d,d,d,d,d,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,
`,`,d,d,d,d,d,d,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,d,d`,`,d,d,d,d,d,d,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,
`,`,`,`,`,`,d,d,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,d,d`,`,`,`,`,`,d,d,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,
`,`,`,`,`,`,d,d,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,d,d`,`,`,`,`,`,d,d,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,
`,`,`,`,`,`,d,d,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,d,d`,`,`,`,`,`,d,d,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,
```

The desired result is roughly (done manually):

```
`,`,`,`,`,`,d,d,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,d,d,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,d,d,`,`,`,`,`,`
`,`,`,`,`,`,d,d,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,d,d,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,d,d,`,`,`,`,`,`
`,`,d,d,d,d,d,d,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,d,d,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,d,d,d,d,d,d,`,`
`,`,d,d,d,d,d,d,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,d,d,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,d,d,d,d,d,d,`,`
`,`,d,d,d,d,d,d,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,d,d,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,d,d,d,d,d,d,`,`
`,`,d,d,d,d,d,d,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,d,d,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,d,d,d,d,d,d,`,`
`,`,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,`,`
`,`,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,`,`
`,`,d,d,d,d,d,d,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,d,d,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,d,d,d,d,d,d,`,`
`,`,d,d,d,d,d,d,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,d,d,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,d,d,d,d,d,d,`,`
`,`,d,d,d,d,d,d,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,d,d,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,d,d,d,d,d,d,`,`
`,`,d,d,d,d,d,d,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,d,d,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,d,d,d,d,d,d,`,`
`,`,`,`,`,`,d,d,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,d,d,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,d,d,`,`,`,`,`,`
`,`,`,`,`,`,d,d,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,d,d,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,d,d,`,`,`,`,`,`
`,`,`,`,`,`,d,d,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,d,d,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,`,d,d,`,`,`,`,`,`
```

*How can I horizontally mirror this pasted visual selection in place? Whats the solution for mirroring arbitrary visually selected blocks **in place**?*

1. I've tried visual selecting it and running `:'<,'>!rev`, but that results in every line in the visual selection getting reversed, not *just* the columns actually selected. ([pastebin of result](http://pastebin.com/gxEa15wc))
2. I've tried the `;rv` mapping suggested [here](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Reverse_selected_text), and while that does reverse the visual block it puts it on a new line ([pastebin of result](http://pastebin.com/AiaFf0RS))

The latter ALMOST does what I want, as I can manually yank/paste the reversed block back into place, but this wouldn't work well if it wasn't at the end of the line.

Note the second part of the question above regarding arbitrary blocks, I'd like this to work for other cases where the block-to-be-mirrored is at the end of lines, beginning of lines, or smack in the middle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

vim has an option `ri`, which does reverse insert, I thought it could help for your problem but I didn't figure out how to use it for your question.

However there is always a way to do that. I wrote a small function with mapping:

```
function! Mirror()
    try
        let v_save = @v
        normal! gv"vy
        let l = split(@v,'\n')
        call map(l,'join(reverse(split(v:val,"\\ze")),"")')
        call setreg('v',join(l,"\n"),visualmode())
        normal! $"vp
    finally
        let @v=v_save
    endtry
endfunction 
noremap  <silent> <leader>mr :<c-u>call Mirror()<cr>
```

source it, and visual select the block text you want to "mirror", and just press :

```
<leader>mr
```

it will do the mirror for you. and new text would be always at the end of line. This works for your current question. if you want it to be changed, you can modify the line

```
normal! $"vp
```

ok, I made an animation too: (I shortened you example text, for showing the demo)

[image]

Comment: Nice! This is perfect for the example I gave, but I'm really looking for one that will do it in place. That is reverse a block of text in the middle of a larger block, preferably without the auto pasting. I'd like to cut and paste it into position myself, and then reverse it. (btw, what did you use to make the gif?)

Comment: well, if you want to do `in place` it would be easier than this, you could try to replace the `normal! $"vp` with `normal! gv"vp` didn't test, but should work. @Casey

Answer (score 0):

This works for me, it's a bash cmd, you can script it :

```
while read line; do reverse="$(echo "$line" | awk -F "," 'BEGIN {OFS=","} {rev="";for(i=NF-2;i>0;i--) {rev= rev "," $i}; print rev }')"; echo "$line,$revers";done < yourFile
```

Note that it assumes that you don't want to duplicate the two last columns of your pattern.

Ok for you?

Comment: if you have touched awk, **usually** you could save the `while loop`. also this problem would be done conveniently in vim/editor. since you don't know from which column to which column you want to mirror. if the line is long, counting the column is painful.

Comment: As I said, it is probably more interesteing to script that command